# When using Image.new(...) from PIL importing image what does size start at?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Say I use this code

```
img = Image.new('RGB', (500,500), "white")
```

Is the maximum of the created area 499 or 500?
I understand that the minimum is 0 but I can not find documentation on if the 500 in this case would be inclusive or exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Image.new(mode, size, color)`, `size` is given as a (width, height)-tuple, in pixels.

You can confirm this by checking the pixels of an image with `img.getdata()`:

```
img = Image.new('RGB', (500,500), "white")
pixels = list(img.getdata())
len(pixels)
250000
```

So yes, you get 500 * 500 pixels with your example.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So how are these pixels stored though? I understand that 2d matrices don't actually exist in memory therefore they would be stored in some sort of array I assume. So would pixel 250000 (500,500) be accessed by [499,499]?

Comment: @MichaelSmith yes, the list of pixels is zero-indexed, so if you are going to access the "last pixel" you would do `pixels[249999]`. The `getdata()` function does not let you access `pixels[x][y]`; it gives you a flat list. converting this would not be difficult, though.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the information and help.

Comment: @MichaelSmith sure! I'm glad to help!